# angular view not reflecting controller

Tags: angularjs

This is an angular 1 app.
I have a directive that looks like this:

```
function addLiquidity() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      expanded: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'liquidity.html',
    controller: 'addLiquidityCtrl'
  };
}
```

And the html that looks like this:

```
<add-excess-liquidity expanded="addExpanded"></add-excess-liquidity>
```

In another html I have this:

expanded: {expanded}

This is false by default thanks to the controller that in its relevant part contains this:

```
$scope.addExpanded = false;
```

Now, when clicking a button to show form for adding new stuff, "addExpanded" is set to true.
When then the button to actually save the form is clicked "addExpanded" is set to false again:

```
$scope.addExpanded = false;
```

I can see in the controller that that function is called and that addExpanded behaves correctly in the controller.

Actually, it behaves correctly in the view too. So the value in html:

```
expanded: {expanded}
```

reflects the value in the controller.

However, as soon as I switch to another tab (this app is using nav-tabs) and come back to the tab I was before, then the value in html is not reflecting the controller anymore(which is still doing its job like before, going through the same steps as before, included setting the "expanded" to false).

I tried forcing view update with both timeout and "apply" but didn't help. Also, it seems somwehere else an apply is fired at the end of every function.
I really don't understand what's wrong here. Where should I look? Something happen (I guess) when leaving the tab the first time. But so many things happen so it is not easy to debug. Any clue anybody?

***EDIT***

I added a watch like this:

```
$scope.$watch( 'addExpanded',
    function(newValue, oldValue){
        console.log('addExpanded Changed');
        console.log(newValue);
        console.log(oldValue);
    }
);
```

First time I go to the tab then it will print to console. I then leave the tab, then come back to it. And this time, when clicking on button, nothing is printed to the console.

Roughly, what happens when I change tab is that the div containing the tab-content is set to "display:none/block" (I guess) as it is pure css that is showing tab content upon selection.

In the main controller a few things are done depending on which tab was selected, but I cannot see things that would "destroy" the connection between the GUI and the controller/directive.

Also, each time I go to that tab, I see that the javascript connected to the directive is initiating. And the variable "expanded" is reset to false.

The issue is that, for some reason, the connection between javascript and the GUI is in some way "lost" when visiting the tab the second time (and for all the future until I refresh the page).

Comment: I somewhat understood the problem, but I need to play with the code to find a fix. can you provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The application is huge so it is not easy to set up a fiddle tha includes all the relevant parts. I am adding some more details in the question. If it is not enough I will try to work on a fiddle.